# Deploy API to APIM using Swagger file on Azure Devops

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, swagger, azure-pipelines

I'm new to Devops and Azure Devops.

I need to create a pipeline that would be able to deploy external API's to one APIM using Swagger.

Swagger is also new to me. However, I learnt that I would need to have a repo with the swagger.yaml file. However, I'm not sure how I can then create a build that can then be sent to Azure Portal.

Is there a way to do this? I apologize if this is a stupid question, but these concepts are all relatively new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a special Task to accomplish this.
I'd reccommend this one due its simplicity:
[image]

You need to configure a couple of things in there.
Here's a full-detailed tutorial that I hope you'll find it useful: https://lurumad.github.io/continous-delivery-to-azure-api-management-using-azure-devops-pipelines